# Why is first insert winning over second one in Cassandra?

Tags: c#, cassandra

There are two data centers with 3 nodes each. I'm doing two simple inserts (very fast back to back) to the same table with a consistency level of local quorum. The table has one partitioning key and no clustering columns.

Sometimes the first insert wins over the second one. The data produced by the first insert statement is what gets saved in the database even though I do an insert right after that.

C# Code

```
var statement = "Insert Into customer (id,name) Values (1, "foo")";
statement.SetConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LocalQuorum);
session.Execute(statement);
```

Comment: is the time synchronized between machines?

Comment: This is definitely a time synch issue. You have 2 options to resolve this issue: 1. Either use client side timestamp as suggested by Chris Or 2. Use ntp server to keep the time synchronized between server nodes. In second case your ntp server also need proper monitoring.

Answer (score 2):

Set the timestamp on client. In most new drivers this is done automatically to better ensure order preserved. However older drivers or pre Cassandra 2.1 its not supported and needs to be in query. I dont know what driver or version you are using, but you can also put it in the CQL. Its supported on protocol level though so driver should have better mechanism.

Something like: `var statement = "INSERT INTO customer (id,name) VALUES (1, 'foo') USING TIMESTAMP {microsecond timestamp}";`

Best approach is to use a monatomic timestamp so that each call is always higher then last (ie use current milliseconds and add a counter). I don't know C# to tell you how to best approach that. Look at https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.3/features/query-timestamps/#using-a-timestamp-generator

If you don't have a timestamp set it on the mutation, the coordinator will assign it after it parses the query. Since networks and netty queues can do funny things order is not a sure thing, especially as they end up on different nodes that may have some clock drift.